# JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject exception

Tags: java, json

I am trying to extract the ids from each company_id from the following Json String

```
   String test = ["{\"company_id\":4100,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":4045,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":2979,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}"]
```

I want to extract all the ids from company_id. I am very new to Json and I do not know if I am doing correctly. Here is what I have so far.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(test);
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){  
        JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(0);

   }
```

I am getting this **JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject** inside the foor loop.

Thank you

Comment: It looks for me like it shouldn't have compiled...

Comment: Your input JSON is malformed.  I don't know where you got it, but you should clean it up and then come back to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test isn't a JSONArray, test is a JSONObject. What you actually want to do is:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(test);
```

Then you can access the value of company_id with:

```
obj.get("company_id");
```

Just for future reference, objects in JSON are defined by curly braces ( { } ) while arrays are defined by square brackets ( [ ] ).

EDIT: this is assuming you meant to leave the square brackets on the outside of your String, which would be a syntax error. If you intended for them to be on the inside of your String, then your code should work.

EDIT2: Looking closer at the JSON, there were a number of issues. Here's a valid version:

```
String test = "[{\"company_id\":4100,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0},{\"company_id\":4045,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0},{\"company_id\":2979,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}]";
```

Comment: When I tried this I got this exception  **JSON A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at cha...** . When I removed  the [ ] from both ends I got this **A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1** . What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @danilo Check my latest edit. You had some errors in your JSON string, which I have resolved above.